# Implementation dictonary structure with ValueDictionary lock sync.RwMutex

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, go

I checked how I may implemented dictionary in go-lang,

Why we have 
https://flaviocopes.com/golang-data-structure-dictionary/?

```
type ValueDictionary struct {
    items map[Key]Value
    lock  sync.RWMutex
}
```

From official documentation we have

> Package **sync** provides basic synchronization primitives such as mutual exclusion locks.

Why we used lock ?

Comment: To make the map safe for concurrent use.

Comment: @icza, please define "map safe"?

Comment: You can't write and/or read the same variable from multiple goroutines concurrently without explicit synchronization. `sync.RWMutex` can be used to synchronize access to a variable.